# Unable to fail in HandleRequirementAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I've got an authorization handler that works when succeeding, but fails when... failing.

Here it is:

```
public class HeaderHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HeaderRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    HeaderRequirement requirement)
    {
        var Request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        try
        {
            var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Fail();               
        }


    }


}
```

And it's configured this way:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(nameof(Policy.AuthorizationHeader), //an enum of mine...
    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HeaderRequirement()));

});
```

And here's how I use it in a controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policy.AuthorizationHeader))]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSpace([FromQuery] CreateSpaceViewModel viewModel)
{
    //....
}
```

This works fine when succeeding, I'm reaching the code above. But when failing in the handler I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was
>   specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default
>   schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string
>   defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action
>   configureOptions).

It's as if when failing, I hadn't setup the handler in `Startup.cs`. It mentions `authentication` even though I'm not using that...

From what I can read, `Authentication` is to let user in the application, and `Authorization` is restricting access to certain resources for users that have been let in.

But I'm coding an API, I don't care about the "application" part. I just want to decorate certain action with attributes... Like in .net 4.7.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use an `ActionFilter` instead. Setting the response's content from an authorization handler isn't even supported yet so no point in getting it to work properly.